# React native Collapsing Header with tabs

Tags: android, react-native, animation, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

i am trying to implement this. 
https://snack.expo.io/@satya164/collapsible-header-with-tabview
Now the problem(you can check in the snack) is when user scroll and then change the tab there is some empty space. 
Can anyone please help me solve it ? 
I think its something with the srcoll offset.
Also, Currently, the scroll is on the scrolllview in the tab content. How can i scroll from upper header also?

Comment: Hey Steve, did you able to solve this issue? If yes please do let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's an issue with the library you're trying to use. Check this [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/issues/290) reported in their Github repo. Try to use [native-base](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-def-headref) tabs, if you can. It might help you with this situation. If you are still getting the error, you can generate the tabs manually with your hand written code which I think is time consuming but the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for showing me directions. Currently, only scroll is on the scrolllview in the tab. Also do you know how can i scroll from upper header also?